# How to use mathematical functions not built-in in gnuplot

Tags: libraries, gnuplot

I've always considered `gnuplot` as very useful, and even more since I use `tikz` in L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X documents. Unfortunately, the number of core implemented functions in `gnuplot` is quite small, I often need special functions like modified Bessel functions K<sub>ν</sub> and I<sub>ν</sub>. These functions cannot be written using the existing functions available in gnuplot. Is there a way to bind gnuplot and `gsl` libraries ? I've been browsing [gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/) and other websites dedicated to `gnuplot` bu I found no word concerning this issue. If anyone has a clue, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can write a command that can calculate the function you need, then you're done:

```
gnuplot> f(x) = real(system(sprintf("echo %f", x)))
gnuplot> plot f(x)
```

(see `help system`)

So you can use e.g. octave to calculate your value. E.g., if your system is linux, you can have directly:

```
gnuplot> bJ(a,x) = real(system(sprintf("echo 'besselj(%f,%f)' | octave | grep ^ans | cut -f 2 -d =", a,x)))
gnuplot> plot [0:20] bJ(1,x)
```

It will take some time to run, though! Set the `sample` value to something low until you've set every detail of your plot. If you need to replot many times, you can also tabulate your function first using `set term table` and then plot the tabulated values.

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't think of `system`. For functions I used quite often, it would be worth to compile a small binary interfacing a math library like the GSL to avoid the multiple conversions in the pipe chain you suggest.

Comment: Sure, but in that case maybe it's worth having a binary that can tabulate the function rather than return a single value. In that case, you'll end up plotting a data file with modifiers rather than an analytical function with pointwise system-requests.